# django get distinct object from many to many

Tags: django

I have following models :

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_hiren = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    objects = AccountManager()

class Company(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class CompanyDetails(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ManyToManyField(Account, related_name='employee')
    admin = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

Suppose I have 7 account objects , one admin and six manager (or employee) . Admin has multiple company and five manager are assigned in those companies. Single manager account can assigned to multiple company.

Now my problem is, how can I get all 5 unique employee account objects ?

here is what I tried :

```
@login_required
def employee_list(request):
    employees = get_list_or_404(CompanyDetails, admin=request.user)
  print(CompanyDetails.objects.filter(employee__in=Account.objects.all()).distinct())
```

Comment: define "5 unique employee account objects". unique in what sense? what's the starting point? a `Company` object? And why is there an `admin` foreign key on both `Company` and `CompanyDetails`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always start from the model you want to get. Here you want to get Accounts, so start from there.

```
Account.objects.filter(company__companydetails__admin=request.user)
```